# android screen categories

Tags: android, screen, screen-resolution

is there a way to discover which category my screen belong? I want to know via api if my screen is a small/normal/large or extra large screen... Look at the documentation I ve retrived the pixel density and the width/height of the screen..

thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve `density` and `densityDpi` via [DisplayMetrics](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html). Depending the results you can determine by yourself if you have hdpi, mdpi or ldpi.

Clarification: If the `density` returns a value below 1, you have a LDPI screen. Exactly 1 you have a MDPI screen and more than 1 you have a HDPI screen (read the [documentation of density](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html#density))

Comment: but standing at http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html, table 1, it is possibile to have a hdpi, mdpi or ldpi normal screen. My question was a bit different..

Comment: updated my answer. Maybe next time you should read the documentation link someone gives you...